# Indexing Word Documents and PDFs with Sphinx

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I have a website where users upload documents in .doc and .pdf format.  I am using Sphinx to conduct full text searches on my SQL database (MySQL).  What is the best way to index these file formats with Sphinx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Sphinx can't index those file types directly. You'll need to either import the textual contents into a database, or into [an XML format that Sphinx can understand](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.8.html#xmlpipe).

Comment: Would you recommend one method over another?

Comment: Depends what server-side language you're using. If it's Ruby/Rails, I know all the libraries don't support XML out of the box, unless you're building a system from scratch (instead of, say, using ActiveRecord). So I'd use the database.

Otherwise, it's completely up to you. If you're not using Ruby, have a look at what libraries are out there for your language of choice, see what they can/can't do.

Answer (score 9):

The method I use for this is pdf2text and antiword. I use both of these to dump the contents of the pdfs and word documents into the database. From there it's easy to crawl with Sphinx.

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone used Tika to index other types of documents, much like the SOLR plugin?
[Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/1.2/formats.html)

Some links:

1. [PDF2TEXT is in poppler or poppler-utils on Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext)
2. [ANTIWORD -- seems to be for old .doc, not newer .docx](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/)