# Publish Word documents with Sphinx

Tags: ms-word, python-sphinx

My project is transitioning its documentation from Word documents to Sphinx. An intranet page with the Sphinx output is already up and running.

What we'd like to do is have Sphinx also copy Word documents to the intranet page, and reference those with hyperlinks from the rst files. Preferably in such a way that the links are still readable in plaintext (for example, a reference to `./file.doc` is perfectly acceptable).

The documents don't need to be [indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207995/indexing-word-documents-and-pdfs-with-sphinx) nor converted nor generated - just published.

Is there any way to get Sphinx to do this, or do I need to build some scripts manually?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but perhaps you can use the `download` role: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/markup/inline.html#role-download.

Comment: "Preferably in such a way that the links are still readable in plaintext". What does this mean? What would a link that is not readable in  plaintext look like?

Comment: @mzjn If the link is a fully qualified URL, that would count as 'not readable in plaintext'.

Comment: @mzjn The `download` role is exactly what I need, thank you! If you put it in an answer, I can accept it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`download`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/markup/inline.html#role-download) text role can be used to do what you want. From the following markup, Sphinx will copy Test.docx to the `_downloads` subdirectory of the output directory and generate a link:

```
See :download:`this Word document <../Test.docx>`.
```